# How to include javascript actions in Yii CHtml::link?

Tags: php, html, yii

**Situation:**
My current links are generated by the following yii methods:

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->name), array('view', 'id'=>$data->idCategory)); 
?>
```

**What I'd like to do:**
Need to build a link structured like this

```
<a onmouseover="doSomething();" href="http://mysite.com/index.php?r=categories/view">Books</a>
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last optional variable is attributes:

```
CHtml::link(
    CHtml::encode($data->name), 
    array('view', 'id'=>$data->idCategory),
    array('class'=>'linkClass','onmouseover'=>'doSomething();')
);
```

You can put everything in that last array that you need `onclick` `data-foo` `id` etc.

Comment: Thank you. My question is: Now how to implement th doSomething() function code by CHtml::ajax()?